# Outlook load url when body changed

Tags: visual-studio, vsto, outlook-addin

I am developing email tracking application in VSTO. It loads tracking url when tracking url assign in html body. My code sample in send button event as

```
private void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
{
 Outlook.MailItem mailItem = Item as Outlook.MailItem;
 string body = mailItem.HTMLBody;
 string imagurl = String.Format("<img id='shtracking' src='{0}'  border='0' 
 width='0' height='0'>",emailTrack);

int index2 = body.IndexOf("</body>");
            string finalResult = body.Insert(index2, imagurl);
            mailItem.HTMLBody = finalResult; //issue
}
```

It reloads the page before sent message. Is anyway to block the request before sent email ?

Thanks

Comment: When exactly does your code run? In response to which OOM event?

Comment: I am running inside Sent event.  private void Application_ItemSend(object Item, ref bool Cancel)
        {   // All code here }

Comment: Hmmm... Does that happen hen you set the HTMLBody property or when your event handler returns while Outlook is still displaying the message?

Comment: It is happen when HTMLbody property set

Answer (score 0):

Try to cancel the submission (set the Cancel parameter to true) and start a timer - by the time it fires, you will be out of the Send event handler, so yo would be able to call `MailItem.Close` to close the inspector. You can then set the `HTMLBody` property and call `Send` again. Mark the item somehow to avoid processing it in the Send event again.